# Angular2+ Validate dynamic form on modal input injection

Tags: javascript, forms, angular, validation, angular2-forms

I have a form where you can add dynamic inputs. These inputs can be typed or you can add text from a modal by selecting a value.

When typing into the input the form gets validated, but selecting a value from the modal does not validate the form even though the input is filled out.

Here is a simplified version of my template:

```
// form.component.html
<form #filterForm="ngForm">
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let data of droppedData; let i = index">
                <td>{{data.label}}</td>
                <td><input type="text" required #moduleValue[i]="ngModel"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>

<modal>
    <ul *ngFor="let data of ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']">
        <li (click)="selectValue()">{{data}}</li>
    </ul>
    <button type="button" (click)="useValue()">Use Value</button>
</modal>
```

Imagine my logic works perfectly. Here is my JavaScript (TypeScript) code:

```
// form.component.ts
selectValue(): void {
    this.selectedValues = [];
    for (let value of this.selectedValues) selectedValues.push(value);
}

useValue(): void {
    this.filterForm.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName('input')[dynamicValueIndex].value = this.selectedValues; // appends selectedValue to form

    /****************************************
     *INSERT MAGICAL VALIDATE FORM LOGIC HERE
     ****************************************/

    this.modal.hide();
}
```

When I type into the input the form gets validated, but selecting a value from the modal and injecting that value into the form's input does not validate the form.

I wish Angular would allow me to set the form validity like `this.filterForm.valid = true` in my `useValue()` method, but I get this error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property valid of [object Object] which has only a getter`

Let me know if you have any suggestions to magically validate my form. Thanks!

Comment: Is it necessary for you to stick with template driven form instead of reactive? You current form looks template driven, the answer differs based on which type you choose

Comment: Doesn't need to be template driven, I can change it if necessary

Comment: How are you dynamically adding and deleting the input fields?

Comment: Through a drag and drop. I've updated my HTML a little bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by using `@ViewChild` referencing `#filterButton` in the template and then playing with the disabled attribute in its nativeElement in my `useValue()` method.

**form.component.ts**

```
@ViewChild('filterButton') filterButton: any;

// other code

private useValue(): void {
    // some more other code
    this.filterButton.nativeElement.disabled = false;
}
```

**form.component.html**

```
<button #filterButton type="button" (click)="useValue()">Use Value</button>
```